# Google play market autocomplete icon

Tags: android, seo, google-play, deep-linking

When i search my app in

> Google Play Store

I find that google autocomplete my app without my icon (as you can see in the image above).
I tried to add to my app manifest the line: `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`  with no success.

Should i add something else to my manifest so google will autocomplete to user my application with the icon?

Example to be clear:

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is part of a public API. Such icon generally appears on most popular apps. The result you're showing is not necessarily your app, but a search result. (If you click on it, it will not open your app description page, but a search result)

Comment: Yes you are right, it open serach result. But My app is popular. Maybe i should add something to Google Play Developer Console?

Comment: No, as I said, this is not part of a public API. There is no documentation about this. It also seems to be a generic word, compared to a brand such as the first result.

Comment: What about AppIndexApi isn't it help for what i want?

Comment: I think this is only for Google search results (not in app store)

Comment: weird. It have to be something i can do event just to enhance my chance for icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answered is that there is not way to control it because there is no Google API for this.

@Simon Marquis answer:

> "This is not part of a public API. There is no documentation about
>   this. It also seems to be a generic word, compared to a brand such as
>   the first result."